# how to make a button that will copy the value of the multiple radio buttons selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please check the image i attached,

[image: copyy button]

here is my current code,

```js
$("#button1").on("click", function() {

  var radio1 = $("input[name='option1']:checked").val();
  var radio2 = $("input[name='option2']:checked").val();
  var radio3 = $("input[name='option3']:checked").val();
  var radio4 = $("input[name='option4']:checked").val();
  var qstring = "1. " + radio1 + "<br /> " + "2. " + radio2 + "<br />" + "3. " + radio3 + "<br />" + "4. " + radio4;
  var result2 = qstring.fontsize(3);
  document.getElementById("Center").innerHTML = result2;
  result2.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
});
```

Comment: Seems you are using wrong variables.. Instead of `radioValue, radioValue1, radioValue2, radioValue3`, it should be, `radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4`

Comment: @MilanChheda oh i just forgot to edit that part, my current code is using the correct variables, its not working

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the answer. You just have to call the div id which the result is being display.

```
$("#button1").on("click", function(){

    var target = document.getElementById("Center");
    var range, select;
    if (document.createRange) {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(target)
    select = window.getSelection();
    select.removeAllRanges();
    select.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    select.removeAllRanges();
} else {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(target);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```